# Pass Value by Using Request.setAttribute

Tags: java, jsp, request, scriptlet

I am trying to get attribute of spanId and set Attribute by using request. Then I want to pass the output. Although the first input is has value, it still return me null.

Below are my codes. Help will be appreciate! :)

```
<input id="spanId" name="spanId">

<%  
    String spanId = request.getParameter("spanId");
     request.setAttribute("spanId",spanId);
%>

<%= request.getParameter("spanId") %>">
```

Comment: Why do you want to get and set same variable on the same page? Do not use scriptlets `<% %>` in JSP. You can use `<form>` tag of HTML to submit the value to servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getAttribute` method instead of `getParameter()` like

```
<%= request.getAttribute("spanId") %>">
```

Comment: Hi, it still returns me null

Answer (score 0):

Just think if you are setting an attribute to request object how you can get it? by using getAttribute.... String spanId = request.getAttribute("spanId").

Also request attribute has request scope (scope lasts only till 1 request).

More on this over here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html

Avoid using scripting elements in your JSP.. remember you are tightly coupling your presentation and business logic.